# How can I get a variable valued current working directory (pwd) in powershell profile

Tags: python, powershell

I was trying to use anaconda as my Python virtual environment, and my virtual environment is stored in project directory.

Manually, I need to use following command to activate my local virtual environment:

```
conda activate ./envs
```

Before that, I edited script of `profile.ps1` with following code:

```
conda init powershell
```

and which is revealed as following content:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Users\dengyijian\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

So, every time when I lauch my powershell window in project directory (press shift + right click mouse), and I got `(base)` environment.

What I need is enabling local environment `./venv` automatically, for which I tried Including `$(pwd)` command, but I only got `PS C:\Windows\system32>`.

So as my title asking, how can I get a variable valued current working directory (pwd) in powershell profile when I launch powershell in specified working directory?

Comment: Do you mean [$PSScriptRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psscriptroot) ?

Comment: @Theo `$PSScriptRoot` would just be the location of the profile.ps1 file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "Open PowerShell window here" explorer context menu option doesn't do things in the right order to allow for this. The basic command it runs does this:

1. working directory starts at `c:\Windows\system32\`
2. Starts powershell with command to set directory (you can see this in task manager):

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '[explorer directory]'
```

3. Powershell starts,
4. then runs your profile .ps1
5. then finally runs the `Set-Location` command to switch directory

Your profile script has no idea where it's being sent to yet.

---

You can kind of get around this by parsing the path from the command line, using `$pid` to get the process info:

```
# example of command line when starting powershell from explorer in C:\temp\
(Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "Handle=$pid").CommandLine

"PowerShell.exe" -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath 'C:\temp'

# so, in your profile.ps1, take whatever is after "literalpath", then whatever is between single quotes:
$ExplorerPath = (((Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "Handle=$pid").CommandLine -split 'literalPath')[1] -split "'")[1]

# Then feed it to conda however you need, 
# BUT remember that the next command to run after your profile script will be the "Set-Location" above
$ExplorerPath 
C:\temp
```

Comment: Can I get the target directory in profile.ps1?

Comment: @OkeyjaTung yes, that's what the line starting with `$ExplorerPath` does. Add it to your profile.ps1 to get the target directory